# iOS how load a viewController in a tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

i have a tabbarController application that has 4 tab bar item ,i need in first item to open a viewController only here.

I try whit this

[self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:NO];

work and to come back previous view?

Thank's for any suggest

Comment: Please clarify your question.  I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, or what problems you are having accomplishing it.

Comment: I said that i have tab bar application ok? And i want to open a view controller that with this code self presentModal..... work,my problem is to come back or the opposite of presentModalViewController..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I now think I understand the question, but let me rephrase it to ensure that I am correct:

What you want to know is that if you open a modal viewController using presentModelViewController, how do you close it to get back to the viewController that presented it.

If that's the correct question, here is your answer:

on the viewController that has been presented (the one that is modal), if iOS 5.x call

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

if not, call

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: i try but my view controller remain there not dismiss

Comment: I updated my answer to address different iOS versions

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting/testing on?

Comment: i try also with parent nothing i use iOS 5.1 and i load a view controller with [self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:NO];

Comment: Are you trying to call [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO] from the same viewController that you called [self presentModalViewController:Animated:]?

Comment: yes i try from a viewController with both code parent and present by this view controller don't dismiss.

Comment: that code needs to be called from the viewController that you are calling "nvc", not the one calling presentModelViewController:animated:

Comment: i have a firstviewcontroller contain in a tabbar application ok? there i need to load another view controller so in the first case i use [self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:NO]; and when i go in the second when i click a row in a table i want to dismiss this last view controller(second)

Comment: is the table you are clicking to dismiss the last view controller (second) in the first view controller or the second?

Comment: the tableView is in the second ViewController that i want to dismiss

Comment: Great! And, I assume you are calling the dismiss code in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:  You should log out to see if the code is being called and that the self.presentingViewController is nil or not.

Comment: yes log say me that parentViewController is nil

Comment: what about presentingViewController - is it nil also?

Comment: i dont't find a log for presentingViewController

Comment: Add this: NSLog(@"presentingViewController is %@", (self.presentingViewController == nil) ? @"nil":@"not nil"); just before you make the call to [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO]; and tell me what print out you get

Comment: you can't believe me if i write so [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"presentingViewController is %@", (self.presentingViewController == nil) ? @"nil":@"not nil"); work well thank's a lot for the time that you save for me